# Asking Employees to "share" or "like" a company Facebook post

Tags: social-media

Is it appropriate for a company to make a non-mandatory request of employee to like or share a post to promote a company fundraising event?

Example: If you are on Facebook, please like and/or share a post...

Comment: This is a good question. As the use of social-media increases by both companies and employees so too will the gray area around the appropriate use of social media. We can expect more of these types of questions. Upvoting.

Comment: Appropriate or not, it's not uncommon. If it's really a fundraising event, or something else where you actually believe it's worth endorsing, doing so isn't unethical as long as you don't try to hide/deny your relationship with the company.

Answer (score 15):

> Is it appropriate for a company to make a non-mandatory request of
>   employee to like or share a post

It's appropriate.
It's good marketing and a smart use of social media.
And it's becoming more and more common.

The key here is "non-mandatory". Employees who choose to participate can, those who would rather not can choose not to do so.

Comment: +1 This kind of thing sounds exactly like what a company media department should be doing internally.

Answer (score 6):

As long as you're not monitoring responses and acting upon them in some way (e.g. somehow penalizing people who didn't participate), I don't see any harm in this.  You should be careful to phrase it as completely optional and not a requirement of anyone's job.

Answer (score 5):

You could also create a work FB profile and use that for anything work related including promotions like this. This would allow you to still keep a separation of 'church and state' between your professional and personal online activities.

Comment: Yet it would miss the point of the promotion.

Comment: Not necessarily - you would still have friends on your work FB account and could share the information with them. Think of it like a LinkedIn account where you have contacts that might not be in your circle of personal friends.